# how to pass dynamic vars to all nodejs views?

Tags: node.js, express

I have route:

```
app.all("*", function(req, res){

    //i have here some code for example
    var number = 5;
    //real code is doing some selected on rethinkdb

})
```

how to access then number 5 on any view?

**this is not working:**

```
res.locales.number = 5
req.session.number = 5
```

what else can i try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it *almost* correct, but you've misspelled the `locals` variable which is why it isn't working.

Here's an example middleware which will set some variable that will be available to ALL templates rendered with express:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.blah = 'something';
  next();
}));

// Now, from this point on, any template can access the `blah` variable
// directly =)
```

Comment: Just adding to this answer, middleware like this needs to be declared before all of the routes that would ever need access to `blah`